# applicationx-www-form-urlencoded com HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou fazendo um sistema para autenticar o Token (derivado do cartão de crédito) junto a Cielo.
Esse token possui caracteres especiais como `+`

A Cielo recebe os dados via XML.
Fiz o seguinte código para enviar:

```
 private String sendHttpRequest(String message)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes("mensagem=" + message);

        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }


    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string result;

    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Porém o token chega de uma forma diferente na Cielo me retornando Token não encontado, sendo que ela que gerou o Token.
Ao entrar em contato com o suporte do porque eis a resposta deles:

> O erro ocorre quando enviam a solicitação do token sem a conversão de
>   URL-encoding, ou seja, os caracteres especiais (como exemplo +) é
>   interpretado como espaços pela plataforma. Isto ocorre porque a
>   plataforma recebe o XML em um parâmetro da requisição HTTP, utilizando
>   o content-type applicationx-www-form-urlencoded. Tecnologias como Java
>   (Apache HttpComponentHttpClient) realizam esta conversão
>   automaticamente, ficando transparente para o desenvolvedor. O
>   estabelecimento deve avaliar e ajustar o encoding (URLEncode) na sua
>   solução, caso contrário, outros caracteres especiais irão apresentar o
>   mesmo problema.

Creio que meu código esta correto, ao ler [essa url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665558/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-of-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-how-to-send) tentei fazer algo com
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);
ex:

```
var t = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes ("mensagem=" + t);
```

Mas mesmo erro, antes de eu ligar lá e reclamar com a Cielo gostaria de alguma ajuda, pois posso estar comentendo algum erro.

Existe como eu copiar os Bytes e tentar simular esse post por algum plugin do meu navegador? igual faço com plugin 'Simple REST Client' do Chrome?

Tem como eu debugar e visualizar algo que posso ajudar?

OBS: Quando o token é sem esses caracteres especiais, o mesmo código acima funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não seria apenas o caso de [escapar os caracteres do Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx)?

```
var tokenEscapado = Uri.EscapeDataString(token);
```

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` não vai funcionar porque é para URL's, e o que está dando problema é um componente no conteúdo da mensagem, que no caso é um XML.

Answer (score 4):

Dorathoto, inicialmente não consigo visualizar um problema com o seu codigo, o que posso sugerir é que você tente fazer esta requisição usando a WebAPI Client.

Instale o seguinte pacote:

<kbd>[**Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client)</kbd>

Então você pode usar o seguinte codigo:

```
private async Task<string> sendHttpRequest(string message)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("mensagem", message);

    using (var cliente = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var conteudo = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data))
        {
            conteudo.Headers.Clear();
            conteudo.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await cliente.PostAsync("minha url", conteudo);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

você também pode utilizar um `StringContent` no lugar do `FormUrlEncodedContent`, caso precise definir um Encode diferente do `ISO-8859-1`:

```
private async Task<string> sendHttpRequest(string mensagem)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("mensagem", mensagem);

    using (var cliente = new HttpClient())
    {
        var chaves = new string[data.Count];
        var itens = new string[data.Count];

        data.Keys.CopyTo(chaves, 0);
        for (var indice = 0; indice < itens.Length; indice++)
        {
            var chave = chaves[indice];
            itens[indice] = chave + '=' + data[chave];
        }

        var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(String.Join("&", itens)).Replace("%20", "+");
        using (var conteudo = new StringContent(encoded, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
        {
            var response = await cliente.PostAsync("minha url", conteudo);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

então você pode chamar este método da seguinte forma:

```
var mensagem = "Hello Wolrd";
var response = Task.Run<string>(async () => await sendHttpRequest(mensagem)).Result;
```

outra alternativa seria tentar usar um `StreamWriter` ao invés de escrever direto na `Stream` do seu `request`

substitua o seu trecho de codigo semelhante ao abaixo:

```
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream ()) {
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding ();
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes ("mensagem=" + message);
    stream.Write (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

pelo o seguinte codigo:

```
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mensagem=" + message)
    stream.Write(encoded);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Vocêe pode também tentar usar outros tipos de encode no lugar do `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`, como por exemplo o `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: vou testar, com a 2ª opção da requisição invalida..ainda testando..

Comment: @Dorathoto, estranho, em todo caso coloquei um detalhe adicional na resposta, acredito que tenha substituido o trecho errado.

Comment: mas estou agora testando com o Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client parece ser uma solução melhor pelo que vi...como força-lo em utf-8 ?

Comment: Erro:
{"La codifica nella dichiarazione 'ISO-8859-1' non corrisponde alla codifica del documento 'utf-8'."}
Meu windows é italiano, mas da para entender...o erro...pq será?

Comment: @Dorathoto, como você pode ver no source do [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/FormUrlEncodedContent.cs), o mesmo faz uso do [`HttpRuleParser.DefaultHttpEncoding`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpRuleParser.cs), que por sua vez recebe o encode `iso-8859-1`... opicionalmente você pode substituit o `new FormUrlEncodedContent(data)` por `new StringContent( HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mensagem=" + message), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Comment: se susbtituit o `FormUrlEncodedContent` pelo `StringContent`, não vai precisar realizar modificações nos `Headers` do `conteudo`... você também pode usar `Uri.EscapeDataString("mensagem=" + message).Replace("%20", "+")` ao invés de `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mensagem=" + message)`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37974/discussion-between-dorathoto-and-tobymosque).

Comment: você poderia por gentileza incluir na sua resposta o final para o receber o retorno após postar, veja na minha pergunta acabei add o final, e não estou conseguindo utilizar a sua resposta. se possível é claro